# Error nan Insert img with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, nan

I want insert a multiple img with loop when i click, the name of images is "0.jpg","1.jpg","2.jpg" etc.

For this i use an array whith all element:

```
{name: '1', result:1, prefecture: "city", photo1:"0.jpg"},
```

and my loop

```
$('.map area').click(function(){
    index = $(this).index();
    var dir =  questions[index].name;
    var div = document.getElementById("tooltip_img");
    var ul = document.getElementById("gallery");

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i+= 1) {
            var img = document.createElement("IMG");
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute("class", "fancybox");
            a.setAttribute('rel', 'gallery1');
            a.setAttribute('id', i);
            img.setAttribute("src",questions[index].photo1);

            ul.appendChild(li)
            li.appendChild(a)
            a.appendChild(img)
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);
        }
});
```

whith this: `img.setAttribute("src",questions[index].photo1);`, it work because i call "photo1".

but if i want use

```
img.setAttribute("src",questions[index].photo+i);
```

I have a Nan error "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Why i can't use index for call images?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
img.setAttribute("src",questions[index]["photo"+i]);
```